# 4 interlinked (active x) scroll bars

Tags: excel, vba, activex, scrollbars

First, thank you for your time, I am not a VBA specialist but try my self-taught very best. I have been struggling with this for weeks, but can't get it done so I turn to you experts. I can't find an adequate solution anywhere on the web.

The problem/challenge: I have 4 active x scrollbars on a worksheet that need to be linked. They always need to sum up to 100%, meaning that if I pull one scrollbar down (I reversed their scrolling direction, up = up%, down = down%), the others need to go up proportionally - maintaining the 100%.

How it should work is that I have 8 "TA's" - consider them to be markets - for which I each have 4 starting positions. These also define the proportions in which they should move. I have no problems loading the starting positions into the scrollbars. Disregard these TA's, it's just to give you context. It's the movement I'm struggling with. For example:

```
Start TA "xx":

Pos 1: 50%

Pos 2: 20%

Pos 3: 20%

Pos 4: 10%

Sum = 100%
```

Now I move Scrollbar1 up from 50% to 70%. This should cause Scrollbar 2, 3 and 4 to go down with the following proportions, maintaining the 100%:

```
Scrollbar1 + 20%:

Scrollbar2: - 20% x (20/20+20+10) = -8%

Scrollbar3: - 20% x (20/20+20+10) = -8%

Scrollbar4: - 20% x (10/20+20+10) = -4%

Sum = 100%
```

I've tried many options, but the problem is that the scrollbarvalues are both input and output:

1) I just take the output/linked cell and calculate the difference with the starting positions, subtracting them proportionally from the others: this causes a "change event loop" - because the change event from Pos 1 triggers 2, 3 and 4, the change event from 2 triggers 1, 3 and 4, ... and so on.

as such:

```
Private Sub ScrollBar1_Change()

'scrollbar 1 reverse:

front-end output cell pos 1 = ScrollBar1.Max - ScrollBar1.Value

'other scrollbars:

front-end output cell pos 2 = start pos 2 + (difference start 1 and new pos 1) * (proportion 2)

front-end output cell pos 3 = start pos 3 + (difference start 1 and new pos 1) * (proportion 3)

front-end output cell pos 4 = start pos 4 + (difference start 1 and new pos 1) * (proportion 4)
```

If I put similar code in change event scrollbar 2 - 4 it causes a "change event loop", eventually ending in some kind of equilibrium position.

2) I circumvent the change event by doing al the calculations in a sheet, but then then the scrollbars don't always move along with the calculations, causing a functional problem.

As such:

I do the same calculations in a sheet, instead of VBA code:

I take the input from `scrollbar1`:

- start value
- scrollbar value
  -> calculate the difference in a sheet, calculate the proportions for 2,3 and 4 and send it back to scrollbar 2,3 and 4 and so on...

This works but once you start to do elaborate movements the "background values" start to move far from the displayed scrollbarvalues, restricting movements (because max needs to be 100 and min 0). This is hard to explain and show but I'm hoping some of you have experience with this. It's too much code and worksheet examples to post this.

The conclusion is that I need to link the scrollbars in an immediate, simple and correct manner so as that they move smooth and correct, AND SO THAT THE SCROLLBARS ALWAYS DISPLAY THE ACTUAL POSITIONS.

I've been working on it for weeks and it's breaking my back. I can't seem to get it right but as I said I'm no expert. If it were math, I'd simply state something like `scrollbar1.value + scrollbar2.value + scrollbar3.value + scrollbar4.value = 100%` and that would be that, but of course it doesn't work that way...

I just know there's a simple, beautiful solution to this, but I guess I'm just not capable. Thank you in advance so much for helping me out with this one.

Kind regards,

J.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create some kind of "memory" that remembers the last position of the scrollbar so that it only uses those last differences for calculation? Just a thought...

Read about GetScrollInfo and other such commands but can't understand them or get them to work...

Thanks,

J.